# Carrierwave Versions depending on the file extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I hava uploader

```
class PimageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :webdav if Rails.env.production?
  storage :file if Rails.env.development?

  version :preview do
    process resize_to_limit: [640, 640]
  end

  version :post do
    process resize_to_limit: [640, nil]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_limit: [150, nil]
  end

end
```

Help me, I need to file with the extension gif make only thumb version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with something like:

```
  version :thumb, :if => :is_gif?

  protected
  def is_gif?(picture)
    picture.extension.to_s.downcase == 'gif'
  end
```